# Getting the latest distinct object in Django

Tags: python, django, distinct, tastypie

Currently I have a simple messaging-chat app.

```
class Person(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
     sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
     sender = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name= 'sent')
     recipient = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name = 'received')
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True, blank = True)
     message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     conversation_id = models.CharField(max_length = 90)
```

I use Django Tastypie as my rest API. I would like to create an inbox, similar to that of Facebook's inbox where conversations are ordered by the most recent. The most recent message  conversation would show up at the top of the inbox.

The "conversation_id" is the sender's username and the recipient's username put together.

So for example, if user Kyle messages user Alex, the conversation_id would be "alexkyle".

If Alex messaged Kyle, it would still be "alexkyle". If Alex messaged Bob it would be "alexbob".

I have it set up so that the conversation_id will always be in that unique alphabetical order. The conversation_id is what I use to differentiate between conversations.

I have the following resource:

```
class MessageResource(ModelResource):
    sender = fields.ForeignKey(PersonResource, 'sender', full =True)
    recipient= fields.ForeignKey(PersonResource, 'recipient', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Message.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'message-list'
        fields = ['message', 'sender', 'recipient', 'created', 'id', 'conversation_id', 'username']
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        include_resource_uri = False

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(MessageResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(Q(sender__user = request.user) | Q(recipient__user = request.user)).distinct('conversation_id').order_by('conversation_id','-created')
```

This works however! It's sending the data in alphabetical order and not by the most recent recent conversation. In order to use distinct, I have to use order_by. Problem is I don't want the data to be in alphabetical order. I want it to be in order of latest conversation. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line should be like this

```
return super(MessageResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(Q(sender__user = request.user) | Q(recipient__user = request.user)).distinct('conversation_id').annotate(last_created=MAX(created)).order_by('-last_created')
```

In the code I have used MAX method which should be imported with the following:

```
from django.db.models import Max
```

By the way steve has a point! conversation_id seems a bit problematic to me.

**Update 1**

To use annotate with grouping, the values or values_list method should be called:

```
return super(MessageResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(Q(sender__user = request.user) | Q(recipient__user = request.user)).values('conversation_id').annotate(last_created=Max(created), distinct=True).order_by('-last_created')
```

Comment: yeah! I didn't think of it until he just mentioned it.  Check out his suggestion below, also I'm going to give your method a try, I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Django won't allow me to do distinct and annotate together

Comment: Yes, I have noticed now, to use annotate values should be used before annotate. You could find in the update 1 part in the answer.

Comment: I tried it, this time, I'm getting the error: "bool" object has no attribute "lookup". I think the distinct=True is perhaps causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a flaw in the way you set conversation ids.
If you have 4 users, named alex, alexb, bob and ob, the conversation with alex and bob will have the same id as the one with alexb and ob...

About your question, I'm not sure. Your query is a bit complicated, you want to get only one `Message` per `conversation_id`, each `Message` being the latest for the conversation (Max(created)). I do think that you can ease your design around this, by actually adding a `Conversation` model (the primary key of this model can also be a concatenation of usernames), with an `updated` field. It will be far easier to manage, and will likely allow cheaper queries.

Your conversation model can be as simple as

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64, blank=False)  # the primary key is a string
    updated = models.DatetimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
```

Comment: you're absolutely right...geez, didn't know how I even let that go through

Comment: the simplest way to fix it is by adding a forbidden character (at least not allowed for usernames) between the usernames, eg. alex$bob

Comment: thanks for the idea, I was freaking out and thinking about how  I could modify my setup. You just saved me.

Comment: those are all comments :)

Comment: @SteveK I've tried scriptmonster's solution but Django won't allow me to use distinct and annotate together. What are my options?

Comment: His idea was good, maybe the simplest. Try adding the `Conversation` model like I suggested above (do not forget to update its `updated` field whenever a message is added), change your `Message` model by replacing `conversation_id` with a `ForeignKey` to `Conversation`. This will need a few edits but will make your life easier at the same time.

Comment: @SteveK, thank you for your suggestion, could you show me the structure of the conversation model that you suggested?